# java.lang.VerifyError ( this.mc.displayGuiScreen(new ModsGui()) )

Tags: java, minecraft, mixins

I'm working on a Minecraft Client / Modloader with Mixins.

I'm getting an error where when I put this.mc.displayGuiScreen(new myGui()); it decides to throw a java.lang.VerifyError

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Shall we play a game?

Time: 06/08/18 21:16
Description: Initializing game

java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
net/minecraft/client/gui/GuiMainMenu.actionPerformed(Lnet/minecraft/client/gui/GuiButton;)V @247: invokevirtual
  Reason:
Type 'me/conorthedev/pml/gui/ModsGui' (current frame, stack[1]) is not 
assignable to 'net/minecraft/client/gui/GuiScreen'
```

Code: https://github.com/ConorTheDev/PufferfishModLoader, classes: [MixinGuiMainMenu (line 274)](https://github.com/PufferfishModloader/PufferfishModLoader/blob/master/src/main/java/me/conorthedev/pml/mixins/MixinGuiMainMenu.java#L274) and ModsGui is the Gui I'm trying to display.

If anyone can help me that would be great.

Comment: Line 274 of `MixinMinecraft` (https://github.com/ConorTheDev/PufferfishModLoader/blob/443d03c932750fd498909e173ffbec662605e97f/src/main/java/me/conorthedev/pml/mixins/MixinMinecraft.java#L274) is just a closing brace.

Comment: @NRitH MixinGuiMainMenu I meant haha

Comment: Are you running it locally or on some server?

Comment: I can't find ModsGui in your repository. Neither can GitHub.